# How to get a route for a truck with these options grossWeight height length

Tags: here-api

grossWeight = 20000 kg
height = 5000 centimeters 
length = 9000 centimeters 
I have already read this
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.9.1/api-reference-swagger.html
but I don't understand how to use these parameters
**my example route, bridge traffic for trucks is prohibited**
[image]
**map with Weight restrictions, my test route bridge marked as yellow**
[image]
**my postman request example**
[image]
in response from the server I get this polyline :

> BG0zu0sDok2-tB7WkQvRwMnGgF3IwHzFoGnG0KrE4IjD4IrEgPjDoLzUrOrEjD_EjDnL7G7L_EvMrEvMvC7LnB7GUvHoBnLkDvMoGzKoGzjB8V_nBsYjNwH7a0P3XkNoGkhBoBwHkDkS0F8fsJozBgFkcwC8LwC8LzoBkcnG7f_EnajDnQ3DrTvMv-B7B_JnG7fnBnGnBnGnB7GnBnGvHrnB3S3iDzP7xC7G7kBrYz9DrJjwBnBnGnB7GnB7G_ErY3DzU8BvRAnLT3N7BnajDnkBvCrdvCvMrJ7zBzFnf3D3SrE_YTrE_Jz8BjI3wBnBvHnGvlBvC_O7B7LTjD3NvyC3DrY_T0U3S0ZsT4iDwCwMgFkXsJ8fwMgyBUgFoBgK4D0ZwCgPsEgZkDwRkD8Q4DsTzFoG7QwW9NuS
>
> and here is decoded route
> [image]
>
> **The correct route should look something like this**
> [image]

Question:

1. How to specify these parameters correctly?
2. Does the response come with instructions that the grossweight parameter was taken into account when laying this route?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport if it possible provide some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding [Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.12.0/api-reference-swagger.html) the "grossWeight" is a property of "truck" object parameter therefore in the request should be truck[grossWeight]=20000,

   if you want specify additional truck restriction e.g. "height" then "truck" parameter will be truck[grossWeight]=20000&truck[height]=365

   We have Routing API playground [there](http://refclient.ext.here.com/) and [new one there](http://new.refclient.ext.here.com/) there you can see how and which parameters could be defined:

   [image]

   ---
2. No, it doesn't provide in response that the grossWeight parameter was taken because so was designed.